# How can i fix error: incompatible types: tab1 cannot be converted to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-tabs

TaB EC CODE

[image]

[image]

[image]

Error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to create a Tab menu to click on a certain tab. The method has worked on a different project but when I implement it on my MAIN project it always underlines the `return tab1;`.

It says required:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
found: com.example.batyaa.firstgearautomotive_2.cars.chevrolet_equinox_2001;
```

BUT why? I have Fragment imported.

```
public class PagerAdapter_1 extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    int NumberOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter_1(FragmentManager fm, int numOftabs)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.NumberOfTabs = numOftabs;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                tabCE tab1 = new tabCE();
                return  tab1;
            default:
                return  null;
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably issue is related to imports and `NumberOfTabs` from `getCount`

Comment: no even when ihave it return NumberOfTabs; it still  gives me refactoring cannot be performed read-only

Comment: Show both class imports

Comment: i add a screenshot above,but as a link

Comment: @D-TECK : also tabCE

Comment: two extra screenshots should show, but the method i am using worked on an empty project, i dont understand why it wont allow a return of tab in the siwtch

Comment: @D-TECK : we are asking for imports of `tabCE` class

Comment: i created an Blank Fragment named TabCE , its activity was already written, i just changed the text in the layout,so really theres nothing there.

Comment: Your `Adapter` looks fine. `tabCE` imports are the issue in here.  As you can see, it needs to be declared as `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` which probably got the wrong import or wrong package or whatever. You should add the `tabCE` class import-codes to the question in order to to be able to help you.

Comment: I’m new to android and I don’t wanna bother you. But how do I get all class import codes? I copied all the imports on tabCE and pasted them in the adapter Class and still had it underlined

Comment: i added another image

Comment: still it hasnt changed the error

Comment: added another image, they wont allow screenshot until something bout upvotes or somethig

Comment: i add screeshots of tabEC activity

Comment: Defiantly will do, i actually use the log cats always but when i dont understand i ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using `android.app.Fragment` import in `tabCE` class.

**Change the import to :**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

In `tabCE` class and then, in `PagerAdapter` import the `Fragment` as `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

**Also, the `R import` is wrong too.**

`tabCE` is in the `..2001` package but it's using it as it is in `firstgearautomotive_2` package which is not correct. Remove the import and it will show you the right one(**Where your class is**) which contains the right package and then import it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180762/discussion-on-answer-by-w-how-can-i-fix-error-incompatible-types-tab1-can).